# NGINX Proxy Basic Auth & Wordpress Docker Container: wp_remote_post 401 Authorization Required

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx

I have set up a simple docker-compose file with an nginx proxying to a wordpress container. The nginx also handles basic authentication.

When a form is submitted in wordpress, I have to make a call to another service  using wp_remote_post. Unfortunately this fails, since my nginx (confirmed it is my nginx) is sending back a 401 code, asking for authentication.

Is there anything in my configs that could be interfering here?

The response:

```
Array
(
    [headers] => Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [server] => nginx/1.19.6
                    [date] => Wed, 06 Oct 2021 11:30:12 GMT
                    [content-type] => text/html
                    [content-length] => 179
                    [www-authenticate] => Basic realm="Login Required"
                )

        )

    [body] => <html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.6</center>
</body>
</html>

    [response] => Array
        (
            [code] => 401
            [message] => Unauthorized
        )

    [cookies] => Array
        (
        )

    [filename] => 
    [http_response] => WP_HTTP_Requests_Response Object
        (
            [response:protected] => Requests_Response Object
                (
                    [body] => <html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.6</center>
</body>
</html>

                    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: nginx/1.19.6
Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 11:30:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 179
Connection: close
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Login Required"

<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.19.6</center>
</body>
</html>

                    [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                        (
                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [server] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => nginx/1.19.6
                                        )

                                    [date] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Wed, 06 Oct 2021 11:30:12 GMT
                                        )

                                    [content-type] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => text/html
                                        )

                                    [content-length] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => 179
                                        )

                                    [www-authenticate] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Basic realm="Login Required"
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [status_code] => 401
                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                    [success] => 
                    [redirects] => 1
                    [url] => https://www.mywebsite.com
                    [history] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Requests_Response Object
                                (
                                    [body] => "An alternate resource is located at https://www.mywebsite.com."
                                    [raw] => HTTP/1.1 303 See Other
Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 11:30:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 75
Connection: close
Location: https://www.mywebsite.com
Vary: Origin
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
Expect-CT: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: qe0q9we09qe090qw9-TXL

"An alternate resource is located at https://www.mywebsite.com."
                                    [headers] => Requests_Response_Headers Object
                                        (
                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [date] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Wed, 06 Oct 2021 11:30:12 GMT
                                                        )

                                                    [content-type] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => text/plain
                                                        )

                                                    [content-length] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => 75
                                                        )

                                                    [location] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => https://mywebsite.com
                                                        )

                                                    [vary] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Origin
                                                        )

                                                    [cf-cache-status] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => DYNAMIC
                                                        )

                                                    [expect-ct] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
                                                        )

                                                    [server] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => cloudflare
                                                        )

                                                    [cf-ray] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => d989qw8e9df9s8d0q3e8-TXL
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [status_code] => 303
                                    [protocol_version] => 1.1
                                    [success] => 
                                    [redirects] => 0
                                    [url] => https://the_service_url.com
                                    [history] => Array
                                        (
                                        )

                                    [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                                        (
                                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [cookies] => Requests_Cookie_Jar Object
                        (
                            [cookies:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [filename:protected] => 
            [data] => 
            [headers] => 
            [status] => 
        )

)
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

networks:
  db:
  proxy:

services: 
  proxy:
    image: "nginx:1"
    container_name: "proxy"
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
      - devWordpress
      - phpmyadmin
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./nginx/certs:/etc/certs
      - ./nginx/htpasswd/.htpasswd:/etc/nginx/.htpasswd
    restart: always
    networks:
      - proxy

  wordpress:
    image: "wordpress:latest"
    container_name: wordpress
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      ServerName: mywebsite.com
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/db_wp_pw
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
    restart: always
    secrets:
      - db_wp_pw
    networks:
      - db
      - proxy
```

nginx.conf

```
ssl_certificate /etc/certs/certificate.cert;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/privkey.key;

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
      listen       443 ssl http2;
      listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
      server_name  example.com;

      auth_basic        "Login Required";
      auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd";

      # . files
      location ~ /\.(?!well-known) {
          deny all;
      }

      # restrict methods
      if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST)$) {
          return '405';
      }

      location / {
        proxy_http_version                 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass                 $http_upgrade;

        # Proxy headers
        proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host              $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;

        # Proxy timeouts
        proxy_connect_timeout              60s;
        proxy_send_timeout                 60s;
        proxy_read_timeout                 60s;

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass  http://wordpress;
      }


        # gzip
        gzip              on;
        gzip_vary         on;
        gzip_proxied      any;
        gzip_comp_level   6;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/rss+xml application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine your current auth_basic but whitelist your servers that made the wp_remote_post request by their IPs:

```
satisfy any;
allow 192.168.1.0/24; #replace with your server IP
allow 192.168.2.0/24; #replace with your server IP
deny all;

auth_basic "Login Required";
auth_basic_user_file "/etc/nginx/.htpasswd"; # . files
```